# Adding list values from dictionary in json file

Tags: python, json

I was trying to make a quick thing that would calculate a few numbers but then the sum came out innacruate. The numbers come really off and I'm not sure why it is that way. Does anyone know anything about this? The way it's supposed to work is, it adds every value from the array `paid-in` to sum and then sum become the value of `paid-in-total`. The same works for `paid-out`.

[JSON FILE] :

```
{
  "date": {
    "paid-in": [
      1.0,
      13.0,
      "hello",
      2.2,
      15.52
    ],
    "paid-in-total": 31.72,
    "paid-out": [
      1.0
    ],
    "paid-out-total": 1.0
  },
  "date2": {
    "paid-in": [
      52.53,
      52.79
    ],
    "paid-in-total": 137.04,
    "paid-out": [
      3.1,
      52.2
    ],
    "paid-out-total": 56.3
  }
}
```

[PYTHON CODE] :

```
import json

with open('data.json') as jsonfile:
    data = json.load(jsonfile)


def paid_in(jsondata):
    sum = 0
    for pack in data:
        for to_sum in jsondata[pack]['paid-in']:
            try:
                sum += round(to_sum, 2)
            except:
                print(f'Error in adding: "{to_sum}"')
                pass
        jsondata[pack]['paid-in-total'] = round(sum, 2)
    return jsondata


def paid_out(jsondata):
    sum = 0
    for pack in data:
        for to_sum in jsondata[pack]['paid-out']:
            try:
                sum += round(to_sum, 2)
            except:
                print(f'Error in adding: "{to_sum}"')
                pass
        jsondata[pack]['paid-out-total'] = round(sum, 2)
    return jsondata


def main(jsondata):
    paid_in(jsondata)
    paid_out(jsondata)
    with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(jsondata, outfile)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your sum=0 in outside the for loop so you are adding it to previous sum
i.e `31.72 + 105.32`

code corrected try this:

```
import json

with open('data.json') as jsonfile:
    data = json.load(jsonfile)


def paid_in(jsondata):
    
    for pack in data:
        sum = 0
        for to_sum in jsondata[pack]['paid-in']:
            try:
                sum += round(to_sum, 2)
            except:
                print(f'Error in adding: "{to_sum}"')
                pass
        jsondata[pack]['paid-in-total'] = round(sum, 2)
    print(jsondata)
    return jsondata


def paid_out(jsondata):
    
    for pack in data:
        sum = 0
        for to_sum in jsondata[pack]['paid-out']:
            try:
                sum += round(to_sum, 2)
            except:
                print(f'Error in adding: "{to_sum}"')
                pass
        jsondata[pack]['paid-out-total'] = round(sum, 2)
    print(jsondata)
    return jsondata


def main(jsondata):
    paid_in(jsondata)
    paid_out(jsondata)
    with open('dataoutput.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(jsondata, outfile)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(data)             #data passed to function after reading from file
```